# MVC3: Should we create a new view for a small change, or place logic in the controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I'm building an application using MVC3 that requires multiple sign ins.  The first is standard forms authentication.  Another is as a barrier to an administrative section and there is a third sign in for expired sessions.

I would like to reuse as much code as possible, but each page has some minor changes in them.  For example, on the expired session, we want to change the username from an editable text box to simply displaying the username of the expired session.  We would also want to change a little bit of text, like a title that says "Session Expired."

What is the best practice?

Idea 1:
Should I re-use the view by adding some parameter strings and boolean flags to the controller which will set titles and whether things are editable?  That would allow me to reuse controllers also.

Idea 2:
Have a separate controller/view for each.  Since these pages are similar to eachother, but different from the rest of the application, I would create a new layout template and then have each view be separate.

Thanks ahead of time, you guys are awesome!

Comment: Looked at partial views?

Comment: Yeah, and if I were to take the partial view approach, I would probably just use another layout and just create regular views which use the other layout... The things that would be changing are the main elements on a pretty basic page.  Do you recommend differently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is personal preference and how complicated you want to make your code.

Personally, and the way I've seen this happen the most, is have one view with some sort of editable flag set in the model that is passed to the view from the controller (however you present it via the view or partial).

HTH!

Comment: Thanks for the hasty reply.  It would be great if I could use a single authentication page with these small changes...  If I do it that way, I think I need to add parameters to my controller action.  Is it of any concern that if I do that, then the user can manipulate those values?

Comment: How I would do it is set the state in the controller each time.  If you are relying on something being passed back to the controller/action that needs to be secure, than you might want to use the ViewBag to hold this data instead of handling with the model (which will be HTTPPOSTed back).

Answer (score 2):

For example in the expired session

Use the same controller and depends of state of session, build the right model and return the specific partial view

```
public ActionResult sessionInfo() {

       if (sessionIsAlive){

          //build the model for the current user 
          return PartialView("logged", model);
       }

         //build the model for the session expired 
        return PartialView("expired", model);

}
```

Comment: I like this for the expired session, thanks!  I still need to address the admin access page, which this doesn't fit, but I may end up using this method in conjunction with Sean's suggestions. Thanks!

Comment: you need like a admin bar or just a link to enter to the admin page?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, the decision have to do directly taken for the model, If you model changes, on each window to follow the standard i will tried to do my views strongly type for each model. Now respecting to the actions, here i will tried to called to the same action, and then take the decision base on the model received.